# Add a content pane in the compiled PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Which package to use to get a content pane in the PDF file. I have attached a pic to show what I mean.[image]

Comment: There is the bookmarks and related options of hyperref.  See page 11 of hyperref manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`bookmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark):

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
```